# Which event is fired for file browse window open action in Vaadin Paper Input of type File

Tags: java, gwt, polymer, vaadin, polymer-1.0

I want to exclude the 'Choose File' button of Vaadin Paper Input of type File and perform the same action using standard Vaadin Paper Input 
i.e., on click of standard Vaadin Paper Input, I want the browser window opened.

I tried to simulate click event and focus event of Vaadin Paper Input of type File from the click event of standard Vaadin Paper Input.
Both focus and click are working properly as expected, but browser window is not opening.

My prototype code looks like this, by this code, I was able to simulate the focus event. Similarly, I tried with the click event, but it didn't meet my expectation.

```
    final PaperInput text = new PaperInput();
    text.setLabel("Text Box");
    text.setAlwaysFloatLabel(true);


    final PaperInput filePaperInput = new PaperInput();
    filePaperInput.setLabel("File");
    filePaperInput.setType("file");
    filePaperInput.setAlwaysFloatLabel(true);


    text.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {             
            filePaperInput.getElement().<InputElement> cast().focus();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Polymer Elements doc reads:

> A paper-input can use the native type=search or type=file features. However, **since we can't control the native styling of the input** (search icon, file button, date placeholder, etc.), in these cases the label will be automatically floated. The placeholder attribute can still be used for additional informational text.

Having said that, I am not sure if it may be removed from the container.

Read this too:

Why isn't it possible to programmatically trigger the file input selection?

> Most browsers prevent submitting files when the input field didn't
>   receive a direct click (or keyboard) event as a security precaution.
>   Some browsers (e.g. Google Chrome) simply prevent the click event,
>   while e.g. Internet Explorer doesn't submit any files that have been
>   selected by a programmatically triggered file input field. Firefox 4
>   (and later) is so far the only browser with full support for invoking
>   "click"-Events on a completely hidden (display: none) file input
>   field.